# Spring looking for Table I did not create with java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'meetings.meeting' doesn't exist

Tags: java, mysql, sql, spring-boot, spring-data

Why do I get these errors in the console after I run this app?

```
2019-11-17 19:49:21.997  INFO 10972 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 7 ms
2019-11-17 19:49:22.140  WARN 10972 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 1146, SQLState: 42S02
2019-11-17 19:49:22.140 ERROR 10972 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : Table 'meetings.meeting' doesn't exist
2019-11-17 19:49:22.160 ERROR 10972 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet] with root cause

java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'meetings.meeting' doesn't exist
```

The existing table I am trying to use is called `meetings_list` in a MySQL schema called `meetings`.  Why is it looking for `Table 'meetings.meeting'`?

HappenMeetingApplication

```
package com.gateaux.happen_meeting;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;


@SpringBootApplication
public class HappenMeetingApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(HappenMeetingApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

Meeting Entity

```
package com.gateaux.happen_meeting;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import java.util.Objects;

@Entity
public class Meeting {

    @Id
    private String id;

    private String nameEmp;
    private int startTime;
    private int endTime;

    public Meeting() {
    }

    public Meeting(String id, String nameEmp, int startTime, int endTime) {
        this.id = id;
        this.nameEmp = nameEmp;
        this.startTime = startTime;
        this.endTime = endTime;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getNameEmp() {
        return nameEmp;
    }

    public void setNameEmp(String nameEmp) {
        this.nameEmp = nameEmp;
    }

    public int getStartTime() {
        return startTime;
    }

    public void setStartTime(int startTime) {
        this.startTime = startTime;
    }

    public int getEndTime() {
        return endTime;
    }

    public void setEndTime(int endTime) {
        this.endTime = endTime;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (!(o instanceof Meeting)) return false;
        Meeting meeting = (Meeting) o;
        return startTime == meeting.startTime &&
                endTime == meeting.endTime &&
                Objects.equals(id, meeting.id) &&
                Objects.equals(nameEmp, meeting.nameEmp);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(id, nameEmp, startTime, endTime);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Meeting{" +
                "id='" + id + '\'' +
                ", nameEmp='" + nameEmp + '\'' +
                ", startTime=" + startTime +
                ", endTime=" + endTime +
                '}';
    }

}
```

MeetingController

```
package com.gateaux.happen_meeting;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;

@Controller
public class MeetingController {

    @Autowired
    private MeetingService meetingService;


    @GetMapping("/meeting")
    public String meetingView(Model model) {

        ///////////////////
        //FOR INPUT FORM///
        ///////////////////
        model.addAttribute("meeting", new Meeting());

        ///////////////////////
        //FOR LIST FROM DB/////
        //USED IN HTML TABLE///
        ///////////////////////
        model.addAttribute("meetings", meetingService.getAllMeetings());

        return "meeting";
    }

    //POST FORM DATA TO DATABASE
    @PostMapping("/meeting")
    public String meetingSubmit(@ModelAttribute Meeting meeting) {

        ///////////////////////////////
        //ADD NEW MEETING DATA TO DB///
        ///////////////////////////////
        meetingService.addMeeting(meeting);

        ///////////////////////////////
        //REDIRECT SO FORM AND TABLE///
        //CAN WORK ON SAME PAGE////////
        ///////////////////////////////
        return "redirect:/meeting";
    }


}
```

MeetingService

```
package com.gateaux.happen_meeting;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

@Service
public class MeetingService {

    @Autowired
    private MeetingRepository meetingRepository;

    //////////////////////////////////////////////////
    ///SAVE FORM INPUT OF MEETING TO DATABASE TABLE///
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////
    public void addMeeting(Meeting meeting) {

        meetingRepository.save(meeting);

    }

    /////////////////////////////////
    ///DISPLAY LIST OF ALL MEETINGS//
    /////////////////////////////////
    public List<Meeting> getAllMeetings() {

        List<Meeting> meetings = new ArrayList<>();

        meetingRepository.findAll().forEach(meetings::add);

        return meetings;
    }






}
```

MeetingRepository

```
package com.gateaux.happen_meeting;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import java.util.List;

@Repository
public interface MeetingRepository extends JpaRepository<Meeting, String> {



}
```

MySQL Database

```
CREATE DATABASE meetings;

USE meetings;

CREATE TABLE meetings_list (
    id varchar(255),
    name_emp varchar(255),
    start_time int,
    end_time int
    );

INSERT INTO meetings_list (id, name_emp, start_time, end_time)
VALUES ('1', 'Bob Smith', 10, 12);
```

meeting.html

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
</head>
<body>

<form action="#" th:action="@{/meeting}" th:object="${meeting}" method="post">

    <p>Id: <input type="text" th:field="*{id}"/></p>
    <p> Meeting ID : <input type="text" th:field="*{id}"/></p>
    <p> Employee Name : <input type="text" th:field="*{nameEmp}"/></p>
    <p>Start Time : <input type="text" th:field="*{startTime}"/></p>
    <p>End Time : <input type="text" th:field="*{endTime}"/></p>
    <p><input type="submit" value="Submit"/> </p>
</form>

<h1>Current Meetings</h1>

<table>
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Id</th>
        <th>Employee Name</th>
        <th>Start Time</th>
        <th>End Time</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <!-- if true, display this No Meetings Available      -->
    <tr th:if="${!meetings}">
        <td colspan="2"> No Meetings Available</td>
    </tr>
    <!--  otherwise, iterate over list and display info      -->
    <tr th:each="meeting : ${meetings}">
        <td><span th:text="${meeting.id}">Id</span></td>
        <td><span th:text="${meeting.nameEmp}">Employee Name</span></td>
        <td><span th:text="${meeting.startTime}">Start</span></td>
        <td><span th:text="${meeting.endTime}">End</span></td>

    </tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

application.properties

```
#Database Configuration
#provide jdbc url for the database
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/meetings?useUnicode=true&useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC
#provide username and password
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=somePassWord
#provide driver class name, here we are using mysql database
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
```

POM

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.1.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.gateaux</groupId>
    <artifactId>happen_meeting</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>happen_meeting</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Errors in Console

```
2019-11-17 19:49:21.997  INFO 10972 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 7 ms
2019-11-17 19:49:22.140  WARN 10972 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 1146, SQLState: 42S02
2019-11-17 19:49:22.140 ERROR 10972 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : Table 'meetings.meeting' doesn't exist
2019-11-17 19:49:22.160 ERROR 10972 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet] with root cause

java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'meetings.meeting' doesn't exist
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:120) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.18.jar:8.0.18]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:97) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.18.jar:8.0.18]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.18.jar:8.0.18]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:953) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.18.jar:8.0.18]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeQuery(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1003) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.18.jar:8.0.18]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(ProxyPreparedStatement.java:52) ~[HikariCP-3.4.1.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java) ~[HikariCP-3.4.1.jar:na]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:57) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.8.Final.jar:5.4.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:2292) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.8.Final.jar:5.4.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:2050) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.8.Final.jar:5.4.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:2012) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.8.Final.jar:5.4.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:953) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.8.Final.jar:5.4.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:354) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.8.Final.jar:5.4.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2815) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.8.Final.jar:5.4.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2797) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.8.Final.jar:5.4.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2629) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.8.Final.jar:5.4.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2624) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.8.Final.jar:5.4.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:506) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.8.Final.jar:5.4.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:396) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.8.Final.jar:5.4.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:219) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.8.Final.jar:5.4.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1396) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.8.Final.jar:5.4.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.doList(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1558) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.8.Final.jar:5.4.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.list(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1526) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.8.Final.jar:5.4.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.Query.getResultList(Query.java:165) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.8.Final.jar:5.4.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.criteria.internal.compile.CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.getResultList(CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.java:76) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.8.Final.jar:5.4.8.Final]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.findAll(SimpleJpaRepository.java:355) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar:2.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.findAll(SimpleJpaRepository.java:78) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar:2.2.1.RELEASE]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition$RepositoryFragments.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:371) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar:2.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:204) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar:2.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$ImplementationMethodExecutionInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:657) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar:2.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:621) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar:2.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:605) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar:2.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:80) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar:2.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:366) ~[spring-tx-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:99) ~[spring-tx-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:139) ~[spring-tx-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:178) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar:2.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:93) ~[spring-aop-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212) ~[spring-aop-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy91.findAll(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at com.gateaux.happen_meeting.MeetingService.getAllMeetings(MeetingService.java:31) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.gateaux.happen_meeting.MeetingController.meetingView(MeetingController.java:29) ~[classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190) ~[spring-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138) ~[spring-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:106) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:888) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:793) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1040) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:526) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:861) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1579) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_191]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_191]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_191]
```

Comment: Both of your error traces have different messages. Are you sure ?

Comment: You create a table meeting_list not meeting.

Comment: @Amit Phaltankar @Jens    : I have updated the question to "Why is it looking for `Table 'meetings.meeting'`?"  Also, I've updated the errors from the console in both sections.

Comment: If you don't specify the table name explicitly, then spring trying to find the table as Entity class name. If you have different table name from Entity class, then specify the table name using annotation above the entity class. @Table(name = "your table name")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your DDL your table name is `meetings_list`. However, name of your entity bean is `Meeting` that is why hibernate is trying to map it with a table called `meeting` which doesn't exist.

Either change the name of your entity class to

```
@Entity
public class MeetingList {
...
```

Or use @Table annotation like this

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "meeting_list")
public class MeetingList {
...
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was running the query `String sql = "SELECT * FROM clients WHERE username = ?";`
but my table name was `clients_data` so I modified the string and the `executeQuery()` method did not throw that error again.